# Issues in my Codility example test - Find the first missing positive number in an array

Tags: java

The question was
Write a function:

class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }
that, given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A.

For example, given A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return 5.

Given A = [1, 2, 3], the function should return 4.

Given A = [−1, −3], the function should return 1.
Assume that:

N is an integer within the range [1..100,000]; each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000,000..1,000,000]. Complexity:

expected worst-case time complexity is O(N); expected worst-case space complexity is O(N) (not counting the storage required for input arguments).

```
public static int solution(int[] A) 
{
    int min = 1;
    boolean negArray = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
    {
        if(A[i] > 0)
        {
            negArray = false;
            if(A[i] < min)
            {
                min = A[i];
            }
        }
    }
    
    int i = 1;
    while(contains(A, min+i))
    {
        i++;        
    }   

    if(negArray || A.length <= 0)
        return 1;
    
    return min + i;
}

public static boolean contains(int[] A, int x)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
    {
        if(A[i] == x)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This was my solution and I got 25% correctness. I would like to know what I did wrong.

Comment: Your contains check makes your algorithm run in more than O(N) time, by the way

Comment: Not familiar with Codility, but does it not tell you which test cases have failed?

Comment: @ jsheeran nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the problem down by recognizing that you just need to keep track of the integers you've seen in array that your given. You also need to account for edge cases for when the array is empty or the value you get would be greater than your max allowed value. Finally, you need to ensure O(n) complexity, you can't keep looping for every value you come across. This is where the boolean array comes in handy. See below -

```
public static int solution(int[] A) 
{
    int min = 1;
    int max = 100000;
    boolean[] vals = new boolean[max+1];
    
    if(A.length == 0)
        return min;

    //mark the vals array with the integers we have seen in the A[]
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
    {
        if(A[i] < max + 1)
           vals[A[i]] = true;
    }

    //start at our min val and loop until we come across a value we have not seen in A[]
    for (int i = 1; i < max; i++)
    {
        if(vals[i] && min == i)
            min++;
        else if(!vals[i])
            break;
    }
    
    if(min > max)
        return max;
    
    return min;
}
```

The worst case for looping is A.length + max which is O(N)

Comment: You need to check for `A[i] >= 0 && A[i] <= max` before assigning `vals[A[i]] = true`.

Comment: great call @jsheeran, totally forgot to check the value from A[]

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why they wouldn't create another assessment category for efficiency.

Comment: @KiteThorn it's just part of the overall solution. important to keep big O as small as possible. If you feel my answer was sufficient, please feel free to mark it as the answer to close your question :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this simple way...

```
const data = [-2, 6, 4, 5, 7, -1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 6, -2, 9, 10];
let min = 1;

while(data.includes(min)){
  min++;
}

console.log(min);
```

Comment: exceptional ....

Answer (score 0):

This is my 100% solution for it on javascript:

```
function solution(A) {
  // write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 8.9.4)

  A.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  let smallestPositive = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    const currentInteger = A[i];
    if (currentInteger > 0 && currentInteger === smallestPositive) {
      smallestPositive = smallestPositive + 1;
    } else if (currentInteger > smallestPositive) {
      return smallestPositive;
    }
  }

  return smallestPositive;
}
```

You start a counter with 1 (since is smallest positive integer)

Then if you sort the array you can just traverse it, and after you find the first positive number you compare the values with this counter that is increased if the current value is equal. Otherwise you return the counter.

I recently did all codility tasks on javascript, all with 100% and this might help someone if you are stuck

https://github.com/Buzunda/codility-lessons

Comment: the issue here is that your solution is not O(N) but at best O(NlogN) depending on the sorting algorithm for javascript

Comment: Actually the best case would be O(N) because of Timsort https://v8.dev/blog/array-sort for anyone that uses V8, but the worst case is indeed O(NlogN). But I think is no coincidence that this gets 100% on codility, because of when it appears on the lessons, and I think is simpler this way. But of course your code would be faster.

Comment: I was wrong to assume that at best it's O(NlogN), however when measuring the complexity of solutions, the worst case is used for your complexity. So while the best case is O(N) the worst case is O(NlogN) and so your complexity overall is O(NlogN). If it were up to me, I would not allow your solution to pass as O(N) for that reason. You're only as fast as your worst case when it comes to complexity, in my opinion.

Comment: I agree 100%. I just think that going into coding challenges interviews, is good to have a mentality of not trying to be extra fancy for no reason. If I got that challenge on an interview I would go first for my solution and then when/if the interviewer asked me if I could do it in O(N) I would think and change accordingly. Doing the obvious slow solution that gets you an O(N*N) might give you 50% grade already, my solution would probably get you at least 80%, sometimes 100%. Your solution of course is 100% always but is not that easy everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my Javascript solution for the problem. This got 100% marks on codility.

```js
//Find first missing first Positive number

var firstMissingPositive = function(nums) {
var hashMap = {};
    var max = 1;
    for(var i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
        if(nums[i]> 0){
            hashMap[nums[i]] = true;
        }
        max = max < nums[i] ? nums[i] : max;
    }
    
    for(var i=1; i<=max+1; i++){
        if(!hashMap[i]) return i;
    }
    
    return max;
};

console.log(firstMissingPositive([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,23,20])) //13
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to find the smallest positive integer that does not occur in a given array. The main strategy is to use the java.util.TreeSet, which order their elements. TreeSet is the perfect Set implementation for these kinds of problems.

Check for the missing element in the actualSet that exists in the validSet. See the code below:

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    Set<Integer> actualSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    Set<Integer> validSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        actualSet.add(A[i]);
        validSet.add(i + 1);
    }

    for (int value : validSet) {
        if (!actualSet.contains(value)) {
            return value;
        }
    }

    if (actualSet.size() == validSet.size()) {
        return validSet.size() + 1; //e.g. {1, 2, 3} should return 4
    }

    return 1; // if A array has negative values or just a single positive value
}
```